# Apex Interactive Grid acces in Proccessing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have IG report displaying data from the table. To store  new value of certain RAITING value which is set on the IG report updating I created a PL/SQL Proccess in a Proccessing tab with a code like

```
begin
insert into mytab values(:RATING);
commit;
end;
```

where :RATING is the item of IG report column.

What I expected to get is to insert a number of new RATINGs which where updated via multirow changing of my IG report.
But this code inserts one empty row in my special table. It seems that Proccess created acts as sentence trigger.
Could you advise  how to get access to the value of each row being updating?

Answer (score 0):

Interactive grid you can use the insert operation like below example, change the syntax in your PLSQL Process

```
begin  
     case :APEX$ROW_STATUS  
     when 'I' then 
         insert into emp ( empno, ename, deptno )  
         values ( :EMPNO, :ENAME, :DEPTNO )  
         returning rowid into :ROWID;  
     when 'U' then  
         update emp  
            set ename  = :ENAME,  
                deptno = :DEPTNO  
          where rowid  = :ROWID;  
     when 'D' then  
         delete emp  
         where rowid = :ROWID;  
     end case;  
end;
```

Comment: can this logic be used if there is a join in data source and multiple tables need to be updated?

Comment: yes here you can add the multiple table here